# Detect and query invalid characters which are related with character encoding issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, character-encoding

We have some character encoding related issues in SQL Server.
But couldn't write a query to find all these data.

[image]

As you can see there are some non unicode characters in the Title column and we're trying to write a query to find all these data in this table but nothing seems working.

The Title column is nvarchar and collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

The caharacters in the screenshot are actually Russian but I believe we have same issue with other languages as well.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues rendering Cyrillic characters in an `NVARCHAR` column or variable, which suggests that the characters have already been compromised before inserting them into the table. What do you see if you `CAST(Title AS VARBINARY(MAX))`? I expect that all of the `�` characters are U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTERs which should be rendered in binary as a series of 0xFDFF sequences.

Comment: yes correct  and I see this, "0xFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFF2000FDFF2000FDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFF2000FDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFF2000FDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFF20002D002000FDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFFFDFF2000FDFFFDFFFDFF"

Comment: So how was the data inserted?

Comment: The third parameter to `CONVERT` is not for code page as looks like you are assuming with `1252` and `65001`